# Javascript Tokens, JWT and numbers when decoded

Tags: javascript, jwt, token

I am totally new on using JWT and tokens; I just tried to do this:

```
console.log("logged " + data);  

//prints { _id: 5a82ee98e918b22e83d6c3e0,
//username: 'test2',
//name: 'test',
//surname: '2',
//password: '...'
//[etc]
 //}

console.log("logged _id " + data._id);

//prints 5a82ee98e918b22e83d6c3e0

var token = jwt.sign(data._id, secret, {
                    expiresIn: "24h" // expires in 24 hours
                });
console.log("saved token " + token);

//prints the token in style eyJhbGciOi[...].eyJfYnNvbn[...].usoLRz-[...]


console.log("decoded: " + JSON.stringify( jwt.decode(token) ) )


//prints the token in this way:
//{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"type":"Buffer","data":[90,130,238,152,233,24,178,46,131,214,195,224]},"iat":1519502719,"exp":1519589119}
```

1. why it does not prints the id number in plain text?
2. how can i get the id number i put in the token?

UPDATE:
I am in a login function; data is the answer after login, and it contains the user logged in; i have

```
var login = function(req, res) { 
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, data, info) { 
        if (err) { console.log(err); 
    } 
    console.log("data in auth " + data);
    if (!data) { 
        return res.status(404); 
    } 
    req.logIn(data, function(err) { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log("err " + err); 
        } 
        console.log("logged " + data);
        console.log("logged _id " + data._id);
        var token = jwt.sign[continues on top]
    [...]
}
```

Comment: How are you assigning claims to the jwt before you sign it?  That seems relevant.

Comment: I am in a login function; data is the answer after login and it contains the user logged in; I added code on top post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
Problem was that i put in the token data._id directly as string; as this [link](https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/) says, token payload must be built this way:

```
{
    "_id" : data._id
}
```

so I do NOT have to do this:

```
console.log("logged _id " + data._id);

//WRONG
var token = jwt.sign( data._id, secret, {
    expiresIn: "24h" 
});
```

but I do have to do THIS WAY:

```
console.log("logged _id " + data._id);
var myId = {
    "_id" : data._id
}

var token = jwt.sign( myId, secret, {
    expiresIn: "24h" 
});
```

so now if I use

```
let decodeddata = jwt.decode(token,secret);
console.log("decoded: " + JSON.stringify(decodeddata,null,4) )
```

then THIS WORKS.
Thanks to all for helping me finding the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You are not decoding your token correctly

```
let decodedData = JWT.decode(token,secret);
console.log(decodedData._id);
```

No need to stringify your data. It will work fine. If you get any error, contact me anytime.

Comment: thanks for your answer; i totally forgot to add `secret` ...anyway it does not works, it prints [Object Object] and stringifying it gets the numbers...

Comment: No problem, it's all my pleasure.

Comment: Don't stringify it.